# How to edit a StoryBoard to put it in a Button Style?

Tags: c#, xaml, expression-blend, windows-phone-7, storyboard

I've created a storyboard for a button in blend that I want it to apply everytime the button is pressed, So I tried to create a style,I've been stucked for a long time now.

here is the code of my Storyboard:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="button">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                              Value="1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25"
                              Value="0.85">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                              Value="1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="button">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                              Value="1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25"
                              Value="0.85">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                              Value="1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

And Here is the code of my button style:

```
<Style x:Key="ParametersButton"
       TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
            Value="72" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="{StaticResource PhoneDefaultBorderThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="0,15,15,0" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="72" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="72" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnPressed" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <!--Here is where I want to insert my StoryBoard-->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            CornerRadius="0"
                            Background="#FF1BA1E2"
                            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="foregroundContainer"
                                        FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I proceed ?

Thanks,

Renaud

Comment: Wall of text crits you for 50k

Comment: I'm Sorry, but I don't understand at all what you just said.

Comment: It was meant as a joke. Basically, when you want to ask about something, it's good to have some code posted (it proves you're not asking for the community to solve the problem for you), but having about two pages of code posted isn't very attractive. Make sure you post what's necessary for the community to understand the problem and help you solve it.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Windows Mobile? As far as I know Windows Mobile does not support XAML.

Comment: Windows phone 7 actually, but no WP7 tag exist yet.
sorry for my tendency to over post code but my question seems more clear this way to me.
None of you can help me ?

Comment: There is a windows-phone-7 tag (I retagged the question for you). Can't help you with your question though, but hopefully now someone with WP7 experience might see it.

Comment: Hi Renaud,
It would be a good idea if you can explain what exactly isn't working for you with trying to apply this story board or if you are just asking for a general "how to". I suspect then people reading might have some better ideas what information you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest in Expression Blend, when editing your style, select the visual stater you want, open the storyboard panel and create your animation. This will trigger when you go to that state.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                         Value="White" />
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01"
                                         Value="Red" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```